# Nginx Laravel Php double request per request

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, nginx, request, laravel-5.1

I'm having a problem with my Laravel 5.1 site that is deployed on a NGINX server with PHP 7 on Ubuntu. When I make request for a route the request are being duplicated ,I noticed it when I tried out a function that I had to prevent duplicate request , by generating a new token like CSRF token but for each request.

EDIT
I got the the bottom of the problem, it was the most unthinkable for me, an
img tag with asset thing caused the double request to happen on nginx ubuntu,
I found it out after more debugging with logger and google the problem for Laravel where someone suggested it could be favicon thing so I tried to remove html and found the issue.

This image didn't exist apperently.
""

When I try to `Log::info("test")` on a function in any controller I get the following:

```
[2017-08-03 19:46:39] local.INFO: test  
[2017-08-03 19:46:39] local.INFO: test
```

I don't have this issue on my local WAMP apache server though.

Sites available config (Symlinked it to sites-enabled)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {

# SSL configuration

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot

error_page 401 403 404 /404.html;

#
# Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
# See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
#
# Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
# See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
#
# Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
# Don't use them in a production server!
#
# include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

root /var/www/mysite/site/public;

# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;

location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
#
#   # With php7.0-cgi alone:
#   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
#   # With php7.0-fpm:
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}

# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}

location /pma {

    auth_basic "Auth required";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/pma_pass;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    location ~ ^/pma/(.+\.php)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

    }
    location ~* ^/pma/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
      root /var/www/html;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Show nginx config, show kernel.php (I am not sure of L5.1 if there is kernel.php, the main file where you register middlewares).

Comment: You mean sites available config file?

Comment: Did you configure nginx yourself or did you use some kind of tutorial? Yes post your site config file. Also try doing `Log::info('before'); dd('Whatever');` and see what it does. If you will get `before, before` you know there is some web-server (NGINX) misconfiguration, if you get only `before` you know PHP/Laravel/App is doing something weird.

Comment: When adding dd after the Log::info("before") I get it once, edited the post

Comment: Did you recently updated server software or php packages? (`composer update` or `sudo apt-get update` & `... upgrade`).

Comment: How did you check the double request? In console? Are you using any front end framework such as angularJS?

Comment: @RomnickSusa he checked it using Laravel log file, `[2017-08-03 19:46:39] local.INFO: test...` better would be how does he "invoke" the controller to run, in which case front-and tech might be important to know.

Comment: Try to check it on web console.

Comment: Found out the error , it was an asset link to image that was incorrect causing it in laravel on ubuntu, thanks for trying to help me out!